# how to set grid view item as selected

Tags: android, gridview

I have a `GridView` which uses array adapter to populate the data.

By default when the `GridView` is displayed I have to show one of the item as selected. I have used `gridview.setselected()`, but it didn't show the `GridView` item as selected ( I mean the background of the item is not changed). is there any way to show a specific item as selected when grid view is loaded. Please suggest

Comment: i have set the default selector to transparent and in getview i have set the background color for the selected item. added notifydatasetchange on onitemclick method... it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `getView()` method of adapter do the following

```
if(row != null) {
    if(position == selectedPosition){
        set required background color
    } else {
        set background color to Color.TRANSPARENT
    }
}
```

---

In onItemClick method set `Adapter.selectedPosition` value and call `notifydatasetchanged()` and then proceed with your required logic.

in `<GridView>` item of xml set `listSelector` to `android:color/transparent`

Comment: the method notifydatasetchanged()  did not trigger getView()

Comment: What is selectedPosition here?

Answer (score 15):

I struggled with this a bit yesterday before realizing that what I actually wanted was for the item to be checked. i.e.

```
gridview.setItemChecked(position, true);
```

Answer (score 5):

`GridView.setSelected()` is actually inherited from `View` and just sets the entire `GridView` in your layout as selected.

What you are looking for is `GridView.setSelection(int position)` to select the current item in the `GridView` starting from position zero.

Another useful function is `GridView.getFirstVisblePostion()` which can use to store the current location on the `GridView` (if it's large and scrollable) so that it can be restored when you are restored from instance state (say on a rotation) or otherwise.

When working on such things, it's always useful to look through the [Android Developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#setSelection%28int%29) for your widget/object.

Comment: GridView.setSelection(int position) is also not working. My grid view items background is not changed.

Comment: You may want to look at the layout for the GridView item and check the drawable you are using for the background.  Are you sure it has a different background for the selected state?

Comment: i am launching the app using the mouse in emulator and I have set focusInTouch also to true but still the background in not updated. But if I select any item then the background is changed to the color that I have set in listselector attribute of gridview

Comment: i am not using any drawable for gridview item.  I have set the color using llistselector of gridview

Answer (score 3):

I hope this will help you

```
 gridView.requestFocusFromTouch();  
       gridView.setSelection(1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Check with the following method

```
GridView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.new_image_to_be_shown);
```

This will let you change the background of your selected item as the new image.

And if you want of change the color of the selected item then use-

```
GridView.setBackgroundColor(int color);
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: this changes the color of the whole grid, not the item